# IOT app development

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, azure, iot

I want to build an IoT mobile app(iOS/Android) that will mainly do the following:
user management(login/subscribe new user);add/configure new IoT device; interact with existing devices. Interact with IoT devices is the easiest part for me. What I'm struggling is the first 2 items. For this I was thinking to use a cloud platform like AWS(https://aws.amazon.com/),Azure IOT(azure.microsoft.com) or WATSON IBM(https://www.ibm.com/watson/). Reading the docs of them I could not see how to perform the first task or how to register a new device via a mobile app. Any comments are more than welcome.

Also I was thinking building a database on a server that will manage the users, and sending/receiving messages from the IoT device/app as this app that I'm trying to build is not so data hungry(reading temperature and interacting with 2 relays)

P.S. I know about Blynk.io but the prices/conditions that they are offering is exceeding my budget.

Comment: You can use AWS IoT Registry: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/register-device.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use firebase auth and realtime database.This will suffice your need.

Comment: Thanks. i will give it a try to see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS IoT with Amazon Cognito Identity. Devices connected to AWS IoT are represented by things in the registry. The registry allows you to keep a record of all of the devices that are connected to your AWS IoT account.

The fastest way to start using your AWS IoT Button is to download the mobile app for iOS or Android. The mobile app creates the required AWS IoT resources for you, and adds an event source to your button that uses a Lambda blueprint to invoke a new AWS Lambda function of your choice. Blueprints are preconfigured Lambda functions that allow you to quickly connect the click of a button to the functions that fit you best, such as sending automated emails or text messages or deploying other AWS services. You can download the mobile apps from The Apple App Store or Google Play.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/register-device.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cognito-identities.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to see if I can adapt my application to use this.